# BeanUtils.setProperty method sets null a BigDecimal field

Tags: java, mysql, bigdecimal, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm having a problem using the BeanUtils.setProperty method.
I'm using this JAR:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I run a MySQL query that returns one record and I'm mapping the resultset to a JavaBean that I've made.
Here you have the main class.

```
public class QueryTester {

    public static void viewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE code = 'AA00'";
        try {
            stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);    
            ResultSetMapper<Books> rsMapper = new ResultSetMapper<Books>();
            List<Books> list = rsMapper.mapResultSetToObject(rs, Books.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "root";
        try {
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
          viewTable(conn);
          conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NO CONNECTION");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method that uses the BeanUtils.setProperty method.

```
public class ResultSetMapper<T> {
    public List<T> mapResultSetToObject(ResultSet rs, Class<T> outputClass) throws InstantiationException, SQLException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        List<T> outputList = new ArrayList<T>();
        if (rs == null) {
            return outputList;
        }
        if (!outputClass.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Entity notation not present.");
        }

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        // retrieve data fields from output class
        Field[] fields = outputClass.getDeclaredFields();
        while (rs.next()) {
            T bean = (T) outputClass.newInstance();
            for (int iterator = 0; iterator < rsmd.getColumnCount(); iterator++) {  
                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(iterator + 1);
                Object columnValue = rs.getObject(iterator + 1);
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class)) {
                        Column column = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
                        if (column.name().equalsIgnoreCase(columnName) && columnValue != null) {
                            BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, field.getName(), columnValue);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            outputList.add(bean);
        }
        return outputList;
    }
}
```

mapResultSetToObject method returns a List  with one element that is correct but the bean is set in a wrong way. 
The fields code and bookDescription are set right but kPrice field is set null instead of 3.000 that is the value from database.
I run this code in debug mode and "columnValue" variable's value is 3.000 but the setProperty method doesn't set the right value and the value remains null.

Here you have my Java Bean.

```
@Entity
public class Books {

    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name="book_description")
    private String bookDescription;
    @Column(name="kPrice")
    private BigDecimal kPrice;

    public Books() {}

    public Books(String code, String bookDescription, BigDecimal kPrice){
        this.code = code;
        this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
        this.kPrice = kPrice;
    }

    /* Getters and setters */
    ...
}
```

And this is the MySQL table and the record.

```
CREATE TABLE `Books` (
  `code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `book_description` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `kPrice` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO dbname.Books (code, book_description, kPrice) VALUES('AA00', 'Description example', 3.0000);
```

Why I get this behaviour? What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure which the name of setters/getters is the same of property?

In some case, the problem is that.

See my example below:

```
@Entity
public class Books {

    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name="book_description")
    private String bookDescription;
    @Column(name="kPrice")
    private BigDecimal kPrice;

    public Books() {}

    public Books(String code, String bookDescription, BigDecimal kPrice){
        this.code = code;
        this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
        this.kPrice = kPrice;
    }

    public void setKPrice ( Bigdecimal kPrice) // and not setkPrice or setPrice..
   {
       this.kPrice = kPrice;
   }

   public BigDecimal getKPrice () // and not getkPrice or getPrice..
   {
       return this.kPrice;
   }
}
```